# How to port forward for certain domains on OS X?

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, port-forwarding, port

I'm running Virtualbox on OS X Yosemite and using it for web development. I added lines such as the following to `/private/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.33.1 www.mysite.dev
```

Virtualbox then has these port forwarding rules:

[image]

I'm not totally sure why it works like this, but that's how I got the webserver working in Virtualbox.

Unfortunately, due to how the port forwarding is setup, I have to access my sites like this:

```
www.mysite.dev:8880
```

This is a problem, not only because it's an inconvenience to type the port number in, but mainly because it messes up links in my existing sites (which weren't designed with having a port number in there in mind).

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to automatically forward traffic to port `8880` for my development domains so that I don't have to include that port in the URLs?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand `ipfw` is no longer supported on OSX 10.10. You can use packet filter (see: `man pfctl`) to automatically forward port 80 on your host machine to port 8080.

I followed the steps in the article below:

http://abetobing.com/blog/port-forwarding-mac-os-yosemite-81.html

First you have to make a forwarding rule. Then you have to reference the rule in the port forwarding config. At last you have to apply the rule.

Answer (score 0):

taking a look at your virtualbox port forwardings your forwarding your local port 8880 to the guests port 80

if you change this to forward your local port 80 to the guests 80 then you don't need to add 8880 anymore cause 80 is the default http port

but keep in mind that os x comes with its own webserver which per default uses port 80 so it may conflict until you disable/shutdown the pre installed webserver.